# Android - Should I keep using PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, fragment, preference

My app supports from 2.2 to the lates Android version.
The thing is that for Settings page, I am using PreferenceActivity now.
However, as you know, many of its methods are deprecated and they tell me to use Fragment based settings.
However, I found that if I switch to use PreferenceFragment and Fragment Activity, I cannot support 2.2 and 2.3 anymore because PreferenceFragment is supported above API level 11. 
Even if I use support library, it doesn't contain PreferenceFragment!
I don't know why Google didn't add PreferenceFragment in the support library.

Anyways, I think I can still use the old PreferenceActivity but if it says it is deprecated, why doesn't it support an alternative in its support library?

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because it is deprecated does not mean it stops working - newer devices still support `PreferenceActivity` without issue. However, on larger devices (such as 10" tablets), the dual pane support of `PreferenceFragment`/`PreferenceHeaders` looks much better. Until Google adds them to the Support Library, you can use third party libraries such as [UnifiedPreferences](https://github.com/saik0/UnifiedPreference) to use a single API for all versions of Android.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I will just have to wait... I still don't understand why Google hasn't added it until revision 13. I suspect that they will not add it at all or can there be any other reason? hmmm

Comment: i think actionBarSherlock also has its own preference activity, no?

Comment: @androiddeveloper - it has a `SherlockPreferenceActivity` to add an action bar to a `PreferenceActivity`, but it does not add support for `PreferenceFragment`/`PreferenceHeaders`. Note that UnifiedPreferences works with ABS as well.

Comment: @androiddeveloper - as per [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/43) and [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/411) ticket, `PreferenceFragment` relies on package visible methods in `PreferenceScreen` and `PreferenceManager` and is therefore out of scope of ABS and therefore is more appropriate for another library that specifically deals with Preferences, such as UnifiedPreferences.

Comment: @ianhanniballake i see. thank you. wish we had a single library which is a total port of android 4. today we have actionBarSherlock, nineOldAndroids, holoEverywhere, and now this...